# Is There any way to use multiple where clause in react-native

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I'm Creating a user authentication app & I'm trying to fetch a specific matched user using username & password.

I'm trying to do same like this.

```
var Username = this.state.Username;
      var Password = this.state.Password;
      db.transaction(tx =>{
        db.transaction(tx => {
          console.log("Hellow");
          tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ? AND password ? ', [Username,Password], (tx, results) => {
            console.log(results);

          });
        });
      });
```

but this code return nothing

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with equal to sign I missed equal to sign from the condition

example

```
   var Username = this.state.Username;
    var Password = this.state.Password;

    db.transaction(tx =>{
      db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT U.userid FROM users AS U WHERE U.username= ? AND U.password = ?; ', [Username,Password], (tx, results) => {
          console.log(results);

        });
      });
    });
```